# Trying to run flask app for YouTube API: authlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidClientError: (invalid_client) Unauthorized

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to connect to my web application and am getting a internal server error after loading through localhost.

```
import json

import flask
import httplib2

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client


app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
  if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('oauth2callback'))
  credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials.from_json(flask.session['credentials'])
  if credentials.access_token_expired:
    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('oauth2callback'))
  else:
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    youtube = discovery.build('youtubeAnalytics', 'v1', http_auth)
    report = youtube.reports().query(ids='channel==MINE', start_date='2019-03-01', end_date='2019-03-20', metrics='views').execute()
    return json.dumps(report)


@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
  flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
      'client_secrets.json',
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly',
      redirect_uri=flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True),
      include_granted_scopes=True)
  if 'code' not in flask.request.args:
    auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    return flask.redirect(auth_uri)
  else:
    auth_code = flask.request.args.get('code')
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
    flask.session['credentials'] = credentials.to_json()
    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  import uuid
  app.secret_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
  app.debug = False
  app.run()
```

I have my client_secret file in my current directory, with everything up to date, however I still keep running into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're doing wrong might be the way you are passing the location to the file client_secrets.json in:

```
client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json')
```

Try changing that to:

```
client.flow_from_clientsecrets('/path/of/current/folder/client_secrets.json')
```

To get the current dirrectory you might use the getcwd() method